# What is the general express setup to respond to a post that has to wait for a query

Tags: node.js, express

My react page is sending the post request. My database responds but it's too slow.  The page gets undefined as a response.  I'm not sure what I'm supposed to be doing in general.  Await/ async doesn't appear to do anything. The docs haven't helped at all. Any ideas?

Comment: Too slow for what? No, your page doesn't get a response at all by default, so where exactly is the `undefined` coming from?

Comment: "*I'm not sure what I'm supposed to be doing in general.*" - optimise your database query, and make your react client more fault-tolerant

Comment: ```App('/query's, async (res, req) { let a = await querydb(); res.send({a})```. This will send undefined even though the db only takes a second

Comment: I'm not sure if that's how people normally respond to the front end.  That's why I'm trying to get general advise.

Comment: No, that hints at a problem in `querydb()` which might return `undefined` immediately instead of return a promise. Please [edit] your question to include the code.